# react Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a dashboard component with logout button. On click of logout, using fire-base sign Out and redirecting to sign in component. I'm receiving the following error. How can I solve this issue.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of undefined
Dashboard.componentDidUpdate

  69 | }
  70 | componentDidUpdate(e) {
  71 |   if (e.history.location.pathname !== e.location.pathname) {
> 72 |     this.refs.mainPanel.scrollTop = 0;
     | ^  73 |     if (this.state.mobileOpen) {
  74 |       this.setState({ mobileOpen: false });
  75 |     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `this.refs.mainPanel` exists before you try to set its `scrollTop`:

```
if (this.refs.mainPanel) {
  this.refs.mainPanel.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

or this:

```
(this.refs.mainPanel || {}).scrollTop = 0;
```